# at the same time as or at the same time when

Tags: conditional-constructions, writing, formal-language, academic-writing

The sentence:

> At the same time **as** the value of x decreases, the variable y and its absolute value decrease.

Can we use **when** instead **as**?

> At the same time **when** the value of x decreases, the variable y and its absolute value decrease.

(To me it looks 2 cases above are interchangeable, but one say mostly use of **as** after at the same time)

Comment: `At the same time as the value...` or `at the time when the value...`

Comment: Thanks! @MichaelHarvey, how can I find the answer by myself if I am not native speaker? (I was thinking about the question above for a few days, but did not even get close to the answer that you supply)

Comment: I think it could be expressed "As x decreases, y decreases.", or "y decreases with x".

Comment: @JackO'Flaherty, in high school math you are right. But one needs to include at the same time, because in economics change in one variable does not immediately influence the other variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original example was:

> At the same time as the value of x decreases, the variable y and its absolute value decrease.

This could be be rewritten using "when":

> When  the value of x decreases, the variable y and its absolute value decrease.

Note that in both examples the statement about the absolute value of Y also decreasing can only be true if Y is strictly positive. If it is already clear that Y must be strictly positive, this is redundant. If the value of Y can be negative, this is inaccurate.

If the implication of simultaneity (or near simultaneity ) is not im important, or is already understood, this could be rewritten as

> As the value of x decreases, the variable y decreases.

The use of "At the same time when" in the suggested alternate in the question seems awkward, and probably not needed. If one wants to more strongly emphasize that the two change happen at the same time, or in very close sequence (in a real system they cannot be at **exactly** the same time), one might write:

> When the value of x decreases, the variable y and its absolute value decrease synchronously with X.